# Fancybox 2 not working in Firefox 22.0

Tags: jquery, firefox, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've been trying to get Fancybox 2 to work with Firefox 22.0, however to no avail. I ran this with chrome, which turned out fine. I've downgraded the jQuery version, put https on the link, ran it through Firebug, nothing worked. Any ideas?

Javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script>
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                afterClose    : function() {        
                    slideMove = true;                                  
                },
                beforeLoad : function() {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                    slideMove = false;

                }
            });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/screenshots/flower-big.jpg" title="The Cupertino Florist"><img src="images/screenshots/flower-small.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

Website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/#portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript should rather look like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        afterClose: function () {
            slideMove = true;
        },
        beforeLoad: function () {
            event.preventDefault(); //<--- this is breaking your code in Firefox
            slideMove = false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

... assuming that you have an HTML5 `DOCTYPE`, otherwise add `type="text/javascript"` attribute to your `script` tags

**EDIT** : Well, it's not Firefox 22, I overlooked some lines in your code : `event.preventDefault();` inside the `beforeLoad` callback is breaking your code in Firefox. This **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzqEP/)** doesn't work and **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/SzqEP/1/)** works if commented out.

Comment: Oh, I had the script tag for the jQuery portion , I just forgot to copy and paste it here. However, something's still not right.

Comment: @Andrew : The culprit is `event.preventDefault();` ... see my edited answer.